# SlimDX 11: Setting Multiple Render Targets

Tags: directx11, depth-buffer, slimdx, rendertargets

I'm using SlimDX 11 in my managed Direct3D application. I would like to implement deferred shading. I'm having trouble when I try to set a depth stencil surface and multiple render targets at the same time. Here is my code:

```
// depth stencil view
DepthStencilView dsv = GetD3D11DepthStencilView();

// array of 3 render target views
RenderTargetView[] rtv = GetPositionDiffuseEmissiveRenderTargetViewArray();

// device context
DeviceContext context = GetD3D11DeviceContext();

context.OutputMerger.SetTargets(dsv, rtv);


EDIT:
// create depth stencil state
context.OutputMerger.DepthStencilState = DepthStencilState.FromDescription(GetDevice(), new DepthStencilStateDescription()
            {
                IsDepthEnabled = true,
                DepthComparison = Comparison.Less,
                DepthWriteMask = DepthWriteMask.All,
                IsStencilEnabled = false,
                //StencilReadMask = 0xff,
                //StencilWriteMask = 0xff,
                //BackFace = new DepthStencilOperationDescription()
                //{
                //    Comparison = Comparison.Always,
                //    DepthFailOperation = StencilOperation.IncrementAndClamp,
                //    FailOperation = StencilOperation.DecrementAndClamp,
                //    PassOperation = StencilOperation.Keep
                //},
                //FrontFace = new DepthStencilOperationDescription()
                //{
                //    Comparison = Comparison.Always,
                //    PassOperation = StencilOperation.Keep,
                //    DepthFailOperation = StencilOperation.IncrementAndClamp,
                //    FailOperation = StencilOperation.Keep
                //}
            });

// clear depth stencil
context.ClearDepthStencilView(dsv, DepthStencilClearFlags.Depth, 1.0f, 0);
// draw as usual
...
```

When I set the depth stencil and render targets all at one time then nothing is rendered to the screen. When I set only the render targets everything renders normally...Why might this occur?

Comment: Please show where you `Clear()` the render target and depth stencil views. Please also show where you create the `DepthStencilState` you are using and where you set it as current.

Comment: @Jon I have added Clear() and create DepthStencilState

Comment: If you switch `IsDepthEnabled` to `false`, does it render normally?

Comment: @Jon yes it does render normally...